# Is it possible to share a vector using boost windows_shared_memory?

Tags: c++, boost

Just getting started to use boost library and familiarizing myself with it to find a solution for my problem.

The issue I am trying to solve is the limitation of not being able to use STL containers on windows in shared memory (CreateFileMapping).

I cannot find a single example of sharing a vector using windows_shared_memory from boost. However there are many examples [like this](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/interprocess/quick_guide.html#interprocess.quick_guide.qg_interprocess_container) using managed_shared_memory.

Please advise if this is possible and provide an example, for sure many other developers are interested and would benefit massively from this.

Comment: Not sure it even possible. Different users of your memory mapped file pretty well could be linked against different versions of C++ standard library and have binary incompatible `std::vector` realizations.

Comment: @Ari0nhh I was afraid of that... but I thought boost "magically" can cover this. I cannot believe one cannot share an STL container on windows without special/extra code and a lot of experience....

Comment: It definitively **is possible**. I've created and used solutions for this, even cross compatible between 32-bit and 64-bit applications. Are you still interested in an answer?

Comment: @user23573 Yes of course, this sounds amazing! Please do share... I almost given up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The snippets below are an excerpt of a much bigger project where I have actually solved that problem. Since it's only snippets, I might have a few mismatches. But I'm trying to outline the general process.

The documentation is basically all available in the boost documentation. However it is terse and it has only two small examples for managed shared memory.

With this approach I was even able to share vectors and maps between 64-bit and 32-bit processes. It failed on strings, which I then exchanged for vectors of char.

---

The namespaces first:

```
namespace bipc = boost::interprocess;
namespace bc = boost::container;
```

If the 32-bit - 64-bit compatibility is *not* the issue you can get a way with a simple "managed" shared memory type:

```
typedef bipc::managed_windows_shared_memory                    managed_shm_type;
```

You can even use the basic (more platform independent) type. But that has different implications on the "persistence" of the shared memory.

```
typedef bipc::managed_shared_memory                            managed_shm_type;
```

But if you **need** 32/64-bit compatibility, you need to use a modified memory type. The key element is the definition of `offset_ptr` which defines the memory alignment:

```
typedef bipc::basic_managed_windows_shared_memory
     <  char
     ,  bipc::rbtree_best_fit
        <
            bipc::mutex_family,
            bipc::offset_ptr<void, int64_t, uint64_t> // defines the "alignment"
        >
     ,  bipc::iset_index
     >                                                            managed_shm_type;
```

Once this is done you can go ahead and define the vector (and string) types you need. The basic rule is that for every type you also need an allocator. (Except for POD types) And for the map-type you need both for both, the key and the value:

```
typedef managed_shm_type::segment_manager                    segment_manager_t;

typedef bc::scoped_allocator_adaptor<bipc::allocator<void, segment_manager_t> > void_allocator;
typedef void_allocator::rebind<char>::other                  char_allocator;
typedef bc::vector<char, char_allocator>                     char_vector;
typedef bc::basic_string
        <
            char,
            std::char_traits<char>,
            char_allocator
        >                                                    char_string;
typedef void_allocator::rebind<char_string>::other           string_allocator;

typedef bipc::offset_ptr<void, int64_t, uint64_t>            data_ptr;
typedef void_allocator::rebind<data_ptr>::other              data_ptr_allocator;
typedef bc::vector<data_ptr, data_ptr_allocator>             data_vector;

typedef void_allocator::rebind<int32_t>::other               int_allocator;
typedef bc::vector<int32_t, int_allocator>                   int_vector;

typedef bc::vector<char_string, string_allocator>            string_vector;

typedef std::pair<const SEGMENTID, uint32_t>                 segid_type;
typedef bipc::allocator<segid_type, segment_manager_t>       segid_type_allocator;
typedef bc::map
        <
            SEGMENTID,
            uint32_t,
            std::less<SEGMENTID>,
            segid_type_allocator
        >                                                    segid_map;
```

After all these types are declared you can start using them in your code:

```
// first get the shared memory segment
global_segment = std::make_unique<managed_shm_type>(bipc::create_only,
                                                    shmem_name.c_str(),
                                                    200000    );

// struct that is going to be allocated in shared memory
struct global_sharedMemory_data
{
    explicit global_sharedMemory_data(const char_allocator & void_alloc)
        :   declutter(50, false, void_alloc)
        ,   core_queue_name(void_alloc)
        ,   remote_queue_counter(0)
        ,   segment_id_map(void_alloc)
    {}

    int_vector              declutter;
    char_string             core_queue_name;
    uint32_t                remote_queue_counter;
    segid_map               segment_id_map;
};


global_sharedMemory_data *  globalShMem;

void_allocator alloc_inst (global_segment->get_segment_manager());
globalShMem = global_segment->construct<global_sharedMemory_data>
                            ("Name of Shared Object")(alloc_inst);

// write a string to shared memory
globalShMem->core_queue_name = "Alcatraz";
```